# Laravel 8 Eloquent without relation.relation

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, relation

I need to get model with its relation, but this relation pull their relation which I dont want to have in result. So I tried to use Model::witout() where I used dot notation like in with() clasuse. The code looks like:

```
$receipt = Receipt::where('id', '=', $receiptId)
    ->with(['company', 'currency', 'customer', 'receiptLink', 'receiptPoint'])
    ->without(['customer.receipts'])
    ->first();
```

As you can see I need to remove customer.receipts relation. But it is still there. How can I remove receipts from result?

Comment: Can't you do a ```$receipt = Receipt::select('company', 'currency', 'customer', 'receiptLink', 'receiptPoint')->where('id', '=', $receiptId)->first();``` ??